# Selenium WebDriver Loop Not working

Tags: java, loops, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to open all the tabs in naukri.com but after reaching "Companies" Tab it is failing.
I am unable to reach to "services" Tab and further on it is not running.
Please assist me on this code.

Jeny Mishra

```
    driver.get("http://www.naukri.com");
    List<WebElement> labels =driver.findElements(By.className("mTxt"));
    System.out.println(labels.size());
//System.out.println(labels.indexOf(1));//get the name of labels present in the webpage
    for(WebElement we : labels){
        System.out.println(we.getText());
        }
    //for(int i=0;i<=labels.size();i++){//get the name of labels present in the webpage
        //System.out.println(labels.get(i).getText());
    //}
    WebElement label1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a/div"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(label1).perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
Iterator<WebElement> itr=labels.iterator();
WebElement currentlabel = null;

//if(currentlabel.equals(companies)){
    //action.moveToElement(companies);
    //driver.close();
//}
    /* String homepage=driver.getWindowHandle();
     System.out.println(homepage);
     System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
     Set<String> allwindows= driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(allwindows.size());
    Iterator<String> itri=allwindows.iterator();
    String currentwindow;
    while(itri.hasNext()){
        currentwindow=itri.next().toString();
        System.out.println(currentwindow);
        if(!currentwindow.equals(homepage)){
            driver.switchTo().window(currentwindow);
            driver.close();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }*/
while(itr.hasNext()){
    currentlabel=itr.next();

    if(!currentlabel.equals(label1)){
    action.moveToElement(currentlabel).build().perform();

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    WebElement companies= driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/a/div"));
    Thread.sleep(3000);
companies.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"w");
driver.navigate().back();

    WebElement label3= driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/a/div"));
    if(!currentlabel.equals(label3)){
        action.moveToElement(currentlabel).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    //action.moveToElement(label3).build().perform();
    //Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.close();
    }
        //System.out.println(labels.);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your code is really hard to understand. Possible to clean it up and repost.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to perform mouseover and then trying to click on all the topicon menus. If yes, I just tweaked your code a bit. Please try to avoid Thread.sleep command. This has been tested only in Chrome browser.

```
    driver.get("http://www.naukri.com");

    List<WebElement> topIconLabels = driver.findElements(By.className("mTxt"));
    System.out.println(topIconLabels.size());

    for (WebElement labels : topIconLabels) {
        System.out.println(labels.getText());
    }

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    Iterator<WebElement> itr = topIconLabels.iterator();
    WebElement currentlabel = null;
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        currentlabel = itr.next();
        action.moveToElement(currentlabel).build().perform();
        currentlabel.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        // when login label is clicked, it doesn't open in a new tab
        if (currentlabel.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("login")) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("loginLB")).findElement(By.id("closeLB")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } else { // closing the newly opened tabs
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
    }
    driver.quit();
```